# Android Spinner Toolbar style

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

How do I achieve the material design of spinner in toolbox? I tried the following but my spinner looks like this

[image]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@color/main_color"
    app:contentInsetLeft="14dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="14dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_nav"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

My minimum sdk is 15.

on my onCreate

```
ButterKnife.inject(this);

    mToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_login);
    mToolbar.setTitle(R.string.sign_in);
    mToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);

    SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    mSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

> A menu is a temporary sheet of paper that always overlaps the App Bar,
>   rather than behaving as an extension of the App Bar.

any links would be a great help

***UPDATE***

I have managed to achieve what I want

[image]

I used this

```
 ButterKnife.inject(this);

        mToolbar.setTitle(R.string.sign_in);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                R.array.options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(spinnerAdapter, this);
```

and my xml

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@color/app_secondary_color"
        app:contentInsetLeft="14dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="14dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

***But How do I make It white and the text color of the menu is blue?
also I have this problem. it seems it is too far away? any way to fix this dropdown arrow?***

[image]

***Update 2***

Well after spending so much time trying, I have achieve how to make it white and the text color black 
through this. I have created my custom layout for dropdown style

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_material_light"
    android:textColor="@color/abc_primary_text_material_light"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
```

then added this code on my oncreate

```
 spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

The Only Problem now I encounter is that the press state is not working, it is just a plane white. if you see on the other pop up menu, when you click an item the background color becomes a little bit darker. Also this annoying icon is still too far from the text.

Comment: what one are you trying to achieve, left or right?

Comment: the right one. currently my app is in the left. i need the menu to float above the spinner as said in material guidance

Comment: did you try changing the base theme to Light?

Comment: Yup. but the spinner menu is still not materialize

Comment: Try adding this in Toolbar app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"...Hope it will help. :)

Comment: Don't edit your post with the solution. If you have found the solution itself, post as an answer.

Comment: You Should Check out my Answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28202380/how-to-force-popupmenu-to-overlap-anchor/30023348#30023348

Answer (score 1):

If u want press state to work, you should add a Drawable selector instead of color as a background. 
Selector example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_normal"></item>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make a [color state list resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) and apply it as background for your `CheckedTextView`. As for arrow icon being too far, AFAIK it's because of the length of the children, it goes as far as the longest child. So, no way to customize that.

Answer (score 0):

**try this code for change first item font color or background color for Spinner**

```
Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spn);
        ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();
        lst.add("Android");
        lst.add("Iphone");
        lst.add("Windows");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String >(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.spin_item,lst)
        {
            public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent)
            {
                View v = null;

                if (position == 0) {
                    TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#007f00"));
                    v = tv;
                }
                else {

                    v = super.getDropDownView(position, null, parent);
                }
                return v;
            }
        };
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use  **PopupWindow** to display views/spinner over given view using **showAsDropDown**().

```
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
                View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_logout, null);
                PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
                popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
                popupWindow.setWidth(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                popupWindow.showAsDropDown(logoutParent);

                TextView textView = popupView.findViewById(R.id.menu);
                textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        doLogoutWork();

                    }
                });
```