# How to force PopupMenu to overlap anchor?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, popupmenu

How to force PopupMenu to overlap anchor? I would like to recreate something similar to [this](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#menus-usage):

[image: Menus usage]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `android:dropDownVerticalOffset` allowed me to overlap anchor view:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">-36dip</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Paritosh Tonk's answer is the correct way to do this. You should accept that answer.

Answer (score 16):

Setting overlapAnchor allowed me to overlap anchor view without setting offset:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">
    <item name="overlapAnchor">true</item>
</style>
```

The PopupMenu wraps a ListPopupWindow inside it. This ListPopupWindow wraps AppCompatPopupWindow using this overlapAnchor attribute. All this in the support library.

Comment: This seems like the most elegant solution, thanks! However, I had to add the styling both in the default styles using overlapAnchor (as above) and in styles-v21 using android:overlapAnchor to get the same behaviour on both pre-lollipop and lollipop devices.

Comment: Is there a way to use overlapAnchor without using the PopupMenu from the support library? It has an annoying bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=popupmenu%20scroll&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=135439

Comment: After spending hours I noticed that I used the default `android.widget.PopupMenu` instead of `android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu`.

Answer (score 9):

Alternative to [Paritosh Tonk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3426273/paritosh-tonk)'s answer:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu.Overflow</item>
</style>
```

or for dark theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came here when trying to figure out how to create a popup menu that overlaps its anchor *when the anchor is in the actionBar.* Since this is a prominent search result for that problem, I want to leave the answer here even though I'm not sure whether the solution would work for OP.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <!-- This item will expand into a submenu -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/anchor"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_anchor"
        android:title="@string/anchor"
        app:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/subMenuItemOne"
                android:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="SubMenuItemOne"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/subMenuItemTwo"
                android:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="SubMenuItemTwo"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at using [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) instead?  Those offer a bit more flexibility in their placement. You can specify the anchor view and an x and y offset which would let you define the overlap.